# Cordova plugins for set alarm clock

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm working on Cordova app and I want to find a way to set an alarm in my app.

I have looked at [cordova-plugin-wakeuptimer](https://github.com/wnyc/cordova-plugin-wakeuptimer) but it uses date to activate alarm.

The concept is that the app will alarm user when user get in the area of some location. Can you give any references?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When user get in the area of some location rather then setting alarm you can use local notifications to trigger user.

A user will be notified locally when he enters some random location. Even you can use sound to notify.

For location you can use Google Maps V2 cordova plugin: https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin .

Its Simple and one of the best plugin.

And to set local notifications you can use this plugin: https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications